# Programmatically get all extensions contributing to an extension point in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

For example, I want to get all id's value of menus that contribute to the extension point: `org.eclipse.ui.menus`

I can retrieve it by using the API `IExtensionRegistry`, `IExtension`, but I need to iterate over the tree of `IConfigurationElement` to get the id's value for each menu, which is not a pleasant thing to do.

Is there a better API in eclipse for doing this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IExtensionRegistry` is the correct API for this.

The simplest call to get a simple array of all the extension point declarations is:

```java
IExtensionRegistry registry = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();

IConfigurationElement[] elements = registry.getConfigurationElementsFor("org.eclipse.ui.menus");
```

The structure of the children of the main `IConfigurationElement` depends on the individual extension point. You have to deal with that in your code.

Comment: Actually, we can extend an existing class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader` in order to parse more easily `IConfigurationElement`

Comment: That is an **internal** class and therefore is not part of the official API. It may be changed at any time and may be different in the various releases. This is a **very** bad idea. [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: @greg-449 hi! In Eclipse 4 one can inject the IExtensionRegistry object, but what about the IContributor to filter down extensions? I have not found any solution at all.

Comment: I mean, I could use FrameworkUtil to get the Bundle, and then create an IContributor on the fly, but does it make sense?

Comment: I don't think Eclipse 4 has anything new for IContributor. It is unusual to use the APIs which filter by contributor.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm providing my own part renderer, which should check which extensions are provided by the calling bundle/contributor. I'm finding it's much harder to do this in Eclipse 4.